# Nonexistence of a homeomorphism between a open set and the unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, spheres

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ be a open set and $\mathbb{S^n}$ the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$(i.e. $\mathbb{S^n}=\{x\in\mathbb{R^{n+1}}:||x||=1\}$).
How can I show that there's no homeomorphism between $U$ and $\mathbb{S^n}$?

My progress:

As image of connected set over a continuous function is connected and $\mathbb{S^n}$ is connected, if there was such homeomorphism, then $U$ would be connected as well.

Now, using the fact that all connected open sets of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^n}$, it suffice to show that there's no homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbb{S^n}$.

I know that for all $p\in \mathbb{S^n}$, $\mathbb{S^n}- \{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: One straightforward approach is simply to note that $S^n$ is compact, while $U$ is not.

Comment: They have different homology groups.

Comment: I don't understand why the edit for the last line was accepted.

Comment: Is U a proper subset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you need is:

$\bullet$ Image of compact set over continuous function is compact.

$\bullet$ $\mathbb{S^n}$ is compact.

$\bullet$ With the standard topology, There's no (no empty) open set $U\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ that is also compact (compact in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is equivalent to be closed and bounded, and the only no empty open and closed set in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is $\mathbb{R^n}$ itself, which is not bounded).

By absurd, suppose now that there is a homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{S^n}\to U$.

Than if you define $ {f}^*:\mathbb{S^n}\to \mathbb{R^n}$ as $f^*(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{S^n}$ (we just extended the codomain of $f$), we see that $f^*$ is a continuous function and $f^*(\mathbb{S^n})=U$. but this would imply that $U$ is compact, absurd since $U$ is open.

Answer (score 6):

This is a collection of remarks that should answer your question:

- The most common tool to prove that open sets of different dimension cannot be homeomorphic is [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). See the section on consequences.

  Two open sets on manifolds of different dimensions cannot be homeomorphic either.
  The reason is that if you study the restriction of the homeomorphism to a small set, you get a homeomorphism between Euclidean open sets via coordinate charts.
  (This remark will only make sense if you are familiar with topological or smooth manifolds.)

  However, now your two sets have the same dimension, so this method doesn't work.
- In this case the sphere is compact and an open set isn't.
- Not every connected open set of the Euclidean space is homeomorphic to the whole space. For example, the punctured space $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ isn't homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: The first point doesn't apply.  In this case, both sets are $n$-dimensional manifolds

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Fair enough. I elaborated on the manifold situation and the dimensionality in this case.

Comment: Technically, the open set could be empty and that would also be compact.  But by a trivial separate argument, that's also not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 4):

Since the sphere is compact and open sets are not, there cannot be a homeomorphism between them, since homeomorphisms preserve compactness

Comment: Just to be picky: open subsets *of $\Bbb R^n$* are not compact. Any compact space is an open subset of itself, and it is not hard to come up with less trivial examples of compact sets that are open subsets of some larger topological space.

Comment: you are right! I think my statement is true at least for connected sets in Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: That is certainly true for proper subsets. Since the compact set would be both closed and open, it would be a disconnection if it weren't the whole space. But since the thread is about subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, it isn't a problem with your answer - just noting that your answer needs to be considered in this context.